# Unable to see broadcast packets with tcpdump

Tags: linux, networking, udp, tcpdump

I am launching an application which broadcasts udp packets. I also have a simple python script to confirm that these packets are being broadcast:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('225.0.0.10', 1060))

while True:
    message,source = sock.recvfrom(4096)
```

However, I wish to see these packets using tcpdump but no matter what I try I cant see them. For example, I have tried:

```
sudo tcpdump -nnXi any > ~/out.txt
sudo tcpdump -nnXi any port 1060 > ~/out.txt
sudo tcpdump -n udp dst port 1060  > ~/out.txt
```

The two last command give me empty logs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pls see my answer

Answer (score 0):

With *tcpdump*, you must specify the interface to lsiten on, for instance:

```
  sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -n udp
```

or likelwise with wlan0 replacing eth0.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`tcpdump -n "broadcast and  multicast"`

Answer (score 0):

This works, make sure you use the right interface, `eth0` in this example:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 ether broadcast or ether multicast
```